# How can I use a CanoScan N640Pex scanner over a USB/parallel cable?

Tags: scanner

I have an old CanoScan N640Pex flat bed scanner and a USB-to-parallel port cable through which I can connect it to my PC. Unfortunately neither Simple Scan nor XSane detect the scanner.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (plus updates and backports) with kernel `3.2.0-31-generic`.

`dmesg` tells me this when I plus the cable in:

```
[256411.641910] usb 7-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using uhci_hcd
[256411.872392] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 10 if 0 alt 1 proto 2 vid 0x067B pid 0x2305
[256411.872417] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
```

`lsusb` shows this device for my cable:

```
Bus 007 Device 010: ID 067b:2305 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2305 Parallel Port
```

The device node created is `/dev/usb/lp0`

```
crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180, 0 Sep  9 17:46 /dev/usb/lp0
```

There is no extra information from any of these commands when I attach the scanner to the cable and power it on, though.

I suspect I might need to change something in `/etc/sane.d/canon_pp.conf`, but I have no idea what to put for the `ieee1284` line, since there is pretty much zero documentation for that parameter.

So how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

It should work over parallel cable. Following this page:

[Sane supported Scanners](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#SCANNERS)

You need the following two links and read them:

[Needed driver:](http://canon-fb330p.sourceforge.net/)

[Configuration](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-canon_pp.5.html)

Hope this helps. At least they say it is supported "good" but according to these pages only the Parallel Access might work.

Comment: Yes, I've seen all that. It's far too vague though.

Comment: Have you tried the parallel port? Accoring to the "canon_pp.conf" which I found on my 12.04 the default setting is set to parport. And the settings should only changed here: "# Set a default initialisation mode for each port.  Valid modes are:
AUTO  (attempts to automatically detect by trying both methods)
# FB620P (10101010 style.. also works for FB320P)
# FB630P (11001100 style.. also works for FB330P, N340P, N640P)

init_mode AUTO parport0
# init_mode FB620P parport0
# init_mode FB630P parport0

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "have you tried the parallel port". I have USB ports, and a USB-parallel cable. I've tried tweaking the settings in `canon_pp.conf`, but haven't found any combination that works. The `ieee1284` parameter isn't actually documented anywhere, either.