# IBM Color Flatbed Scanner (MT 0275-011) parallel port drivers/installation instructions for 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, scanner

I'm rather new at ubuntu. I still have got an "old" parallel IBM Color Flatbed Scanner that is plugged in and powered on and would like to know, whether is's possible to make it work under ubuntu 16.04 LTS. IBM informed me that they gave the service to Ricoh. They didn't reply, yet. Probably there's still a USB scanner and the SANE Backend installed in the system but the device is not connected. I've got the original CD that came with the IBM scanner but maybe it's only for Windows. When running the setup.exe the archive administration window pops up and I get the message that says an error happened while loading the archive (CD contains *.cab files). I spent hours reading the scanner section of the Community Help Wiki. The scanner model is neither mentioned in "SANE Project Supported Scanners" nor in "Scanners in Ubuntu". On the CD I didn't find any *.fw firmware files. In Software Center I installed Wine and **after reading the helpful Community Help Wiki for Wine, I finally managed to run setup.exe, install and run the scanning application with Wine. The software doesn't find the device.** Simple Scan says no scanner was found, so I tryed XSane Image scanning program, gscan2pdf and Skanlite. No scanners were detected there, too. **On the internet, I found the site http://www.bioticaindia.com/0275-011.html. It says "Some of drivers are working on Linux OS, for example Ubuntu or Debian". I can't download the .zip file maybe because of my browser settings. IBM isn't mentioned in VueScan's Supported Scanners list. In an email from VueScan, I was informed that VueScan does not work with any parallel scanners.** I couldn't solve the problem.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: another solution  may be a parallel-to-usb cable; this recent post on Mint https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=260011 reports good success with that method; purchased on ebay

Comment: Did you ever get this working in the end? Care to comment? As I am facing exactly the same question, i would love to hear your progress.

Comment: @Nanofunk Unfortunately, I could not solve the problem. The only thing I can inform you about is that I wrote an email to the SANE project's mailing list. As far as I can remember they replied that they recommend installing the scanner in Windows (I don't know any more whether in a separate installation or in a virtual machine) and "pass through" the parallel port to Ubuntu. I didn't try it. As I have still got that scanner, I appreciate if you get your device working and tell me about it.

Comment: I actually started buying VueScan and never looked back. Most of my old scanners work now (I own about 12 scanners). The ones that did not work i flipped on ebay. For your particular solution - did you try the suggestion from @pdc already? A dedicated Parallel-to-USB cable exists and did the trick for me for an old printer.

Comment: @Nanofunk I didn't try it with such a cable, yet. Where did you get the drivers from and how did you install them?

Comment: @Nanofunk Or did you use the cable with VueScan?

Comment: Here is an example on how to utilize the parallel port https://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/2019/02/27/parallel-port-scanner-with-modern-linux/ . Also, see this older post on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/185847/how-can-i-use-a-canoscan-n640pex-scanner-over-a-usb-parallel-cable -- what I did was to utilize the parallel port on the machine, so that worked.